# How to get the params from a model.state_dict() without breaking the computation graph in Pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, loss-function, computation-graph

I have 2 models: ModelA and ModelB

I want to train ModelA with cross Entropy as a Loss:

```
class_loss = cross_entropy(output, targets)
```

But now i want to add the l2 distance of my 2 model to my loss like this:

```
class_loss = cross_entropy(output, targets)
ano_loss = calc_euclid_dist(modelA.state_dict(),modelB.state_dict())
loss = alpha * class_loss + (1 - alpha) * ano_loss
```

The Problem is that `model.state_dict()` deattaches from the computational graph, and thus gets ignored in the backprop.
How can i archieve this correctly?